Compile time complexity (i.e run time complexity of the compiler) of std::tuple_element<N, TupleType>
Suppose in my code I have the line:
using T = std::tuple_element<N,TupleType>
where TupleType is the type of a very large tuple and N is a very large number (think like 1,000,000)
I understand that this line of code has no impact of the runtime perfromance of my program. But what kind of impact does it have on how long it takes for my program to compile (i.e how does this impact the runtime of the compiler)
Basically is the compiler going to solve this in O(N)? O(log(N))? O(1)?
As I see it a naive implementation using standard C++ would be O(N). A smarter implementation using standard C++ would be O(log(N)). And if the compiler does something special under the hood it can achieve O(1). Which of these is true for GNU GCC compiler?
NOTE: I need to handle processing a lot of types for a template metaprogramming task. I never actually instantiate an instance of this tuple type. Just using it as a container for types at compile time.

why not try it?

Last time I checked, you couldn't have tuples with more than 1-2k elements. Check how many elements your compiler can handle.

premature optimization is the root of all bad sleep. I see not dependence on N or the size of the tuple here https://godbolt.org/z/MYKasTjvY.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai the above doesn't answer my question. It is not about what my program turns into, but rather how long the compiler takes to turn my program into what it is. No display of assembly can answer my question unless you implement the entire compiler and show me the assembly of that, but I imagine at that point it is easier to read the source than the assembly

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100157 (which libstdc++/libc++ use since GCC14) and also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pack_indexing

@user23773995 You can click graph symbol down in Compiler panel (very bottom of it, left of "Compiler License") to see compilation time. You may need to click "Clear cache and recompile" (circle arrow, left of bottom bar) first to obtain a result. Though I guess example provided by 463035818_is_not_an_ai might be too simple to produce results.

godbolt shows you the time it took to compile. I made several runs with different N and different size of the tuple. I did not notice any significant differene in the time it took to compile. The assemby is not relevant

the compile time complexity is not guaranteed or specified. The only way to find out is to measure.

@Yksisarvinen yes perhaps too simple. Though, I didnt want to draw a general conclusion, only that I saw the times I saw from the code I did compile. And I suggest OP do to the same, because any general statement will be just handwaving

@463035818_is_not_an_ai ah yes I saw the timer below after my comment, apologies. I did use a lot of copy and paste and bring the size of the tuple to a million and it did seem to increase the time (always setting T to be the last element instead of the 400th one). Went from about 2ms from where you had it to 30ms for a million types. Based on that I am thinking that it is a log(N) operation

No need of compiler intrinsecs to have a O(1) implementation, but it requires a non recursive implementation of tuple (basically class tuple_impl : tuple_leaf<Is, Ts>...{/*..*/}; to have O(1) thanks to overloads)

Here is some (python) benchmark code; it generates several .cpp files and measures the compilation time
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os
import time

mode = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv)>1 else 0

################################################################################
def test(N,M,nbruns=4,compiler="g++",dump=False):

    code = [];
    code.append ("#include <tuple>");
    code.append ("using type = std::tuple<{:s}>;".format(",".join(['int']*N)));
    code.append ("static_assert (std::is_same<int,std::tuple_element<{:d},type>::type >::value);".format(M))
    code.append ("int main() {}")

    filename = "output.cpp";
    
    with open(filename, "w") as f: 
        f.write("\n".join(code));

    if dump==True: print ("\n".join(code));
    
    t = 0;
    for n in range(1,nbruns):
        t0 = time.time_ns();        
        os.system ("{:s} {:s} -std=c++11 -ftemplate-depth={:d}".format (compiler, filename, max(100,N)));       
        t1 = time.time_ns();
        t += (t1-t0);
        
    return t/nbruns/1000/1000/1000;
    
################################################################################    

K0   = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv)>2 else 10;
K1   = int(sys.argv[3]) if len(sys.argv)>3 else 1000;
step = int(sys.argv[4]) if len(sys.argv)>4 else 10;

for i in range(K0,K1,step):
    res = test(i,i-1) if mode==0 else test(K1,i-1);
    print ("{:8d}  {:9.4f}".format (i, res));

Here are some results of this benchmark for g++, where the first column is the number of items in the tuple and the second column is the compilation time in seconds
    1000     0.1180
    2000     0.2778
    3000     0.5414
    4000     0.9336
    5000     1.3870
    6000     1.9102
    7000     2.7297
    8000     3.4909
    9000     4.6301
   10000     5.5416
   11000     6.9635
   12000     9.0365
   13000     9.5808
   14000    10.9690
   15000    12.4870
   16000    15.3192
   17000    17.3485
   18000    20.6380
   19000    23.3920

which doesn't sound very linear. Note however that the compilation time takes into account both the parsing of type (which may take some time for huge values for N) and the test on std::tuple_element
UPDATE
The benchmark can now measure the compilation time for a fixed tuple size with a varying index for the first argument of std::tuple_element (i.e. one should use mode==1). For instance for a tuple size of N=20000, one gets the following results:
    1000     1.4202
    2000     2.8832
    3000     4.0363
    4000     5.4532
    5000     7.0204
    6000     8.2050
    7000     9.6707
    8000    11.1792
    9000    12.1563
   10000    12.9355
   11000    13.9742
   12000    15.4586
   13000    16.4745
   14000    17.5454
   15000    19.1246
   16000    21.5753
   17000    22.6206
   18000    23.8800
   19000    23.6991

which looks more or less linear.

A much more meaningful benchmark would be to use a tuple of the same, constant size and only change the index passed to tuple_element.

@Wutz, gosh you're right; I have just updated the answer.
